# How to merge different csv files in a folder having different entries but one same column?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have 6 different csv files of training data with details as follows :

```
1 chefmozaccepts.csv
Instances: 1314
Attributes: 2
placeID: Nominal
Rpayment: Nominal, 12 [cash,VISA,MasterCard-Eurocard,American_Express,bank_debit_cards,checks,Discover,Carte_Blanche,Diners_Club,Visa,Japan_Credit_Bureau,gift_certificates]
%---
2 chefmozcuisine.csv
Instances: 916
Attributes: 2
placeID: Nominal
Rcuisine: Nominal, 59 [Afghan,African,American,Armenian,Asian,Bagels,Bakery,Bar,Bar_Pub_Brewery,Barbecue,Brazilian,Breakfast-Brunch,Burgers,Cafe-Coffee_Shop,           Cafeteria,California,Caribbean,Chinese,Contemporary,Continental-European,Deli-Sandwiches,Dessert-Ice_Cream,Diner,Dutch-Belgian,Eastern_European,Ethiopian,Family,Fast_Food,Fine_Dining,French,,Game,German,Greek,Hot_Dogs,          International,Italian,Japanese,Juice,Korean,Latin_American,Mediterranean,Mexican,Mongolian,Organic-Healthy,Persian,         Pizzeria,Polish,Regional,Seafood,Soup,Southern,Southwestern,Spanish,Steaks,Sushi,Thai,Turkish,Vegetarian,Vietnamese]
%---
3 chefmozhours4.csv
Instances: 2339
Attributes: 3
placeID: Nominal
hours: Nominal, Range:00:00-23:30
days:Nominal, 7 [Mon;Tue;Wed;Thu;Fri;Sat;Sun]
%---
4 chefmozparking.csv
Instances: 702
Attributes: 2
placeID: Nominal
parking_lot:Nominal, 7[public,none,yes,valet_parking,free,street,validated_parking]
%---
5 geoplaces2.csv
Instances: 130
Attributes: 21
placeID: Nominal
latitude: Numeric
longitude: Numeric
the_geom_meter: Nominal (Geospatial)
name: Nominal
address: Nominal,Missing: 27
city: Nominal, Missing: 18
state: Nominal, Missing: 18
country: Nominal, Missing: 28
fax: Numeric, Missing: 130
zip: Nominal,Missing: 74
alcohol: Nominal, Values: 3 [No_Alcohol_Served,Wine_Beer,Full_Bar]
%---
6 rating_final.csv
Instances: 1161
Attributes: 5
userID: Nominal
placeID: Nominal
rating: Numeric, 3 [0,1,2]
food_rating: Numeric, 3 [0,1,2]
service_rating: Numeric, 3 [0,1,2]
%---
%---
7 usercuisine.csv
Instances: 330
Attributes: 2
userID: Nominal
Rcuisine: Nominal, 103
```

As you can see I have one common column PlaceID, however number of instances being different in each file.

I need to combine all csv files into one final csv with placeID as the sole basis. But for files having more instances, I would like to split the data so that finally all the columns are homogeneously filled and remaining metadata can be replicated for those rows where instances are uneven.

## Sample INPUT :

file 1 :

```
placeID Rpayment
135110  cash
135110  VISA
135110  MasterCard-Eurocard
135110  American_Express
135110  bank_debit_cards
135109  cash
135107  cash
135107  VISA
135107  MasterCard-Eurocard
135107  American_Express
135107  bank_debit_cards
135106  cash
135106  VISA
135106  MasterCard-Eurocard
135105  cash
```

file 2

```
placeID Rcuisine
135110  Spanish
135109  Italian
135107  Latin_American
135106  Mexican
135105  Fast_Food
135104  Mexican
135103  Burgers
135103  Dessert-Ice_Cream
135103  Fast_Food
135103  Hot_Dogs
```

file 3

```
placeID hours           days
135110  08:00-19:00;    Mon;Tue;Wed;Thu;Fri;
135110  00:00-00:00;    Sat;
135110  00:00-00:00;    Sun;
135109  08:00-21:00;    Mon;Tue;Wed;Thu;Fri;
135109  08:00-21:00;    Sat;
135109  08:00-21:00;    Sun;
135108  00:00-23:30;    Mon;Tue;Wed;Thu;Fri;
```

file 4

```
placeID parking_lot
135110  public
135109  none
135108  none
135107  none
135106  none
135105  none
```

file 5

```
 placeID    latitude    longitude   name    address city    state   country fax zip alcohol smoking_area    dress_code  accessibility   price   url Rambience   franchise   area    other_services
135109  18.9217848  -99.2353499 Paniroles   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   Wine-Beer   not permitted   informal    no_accessibility    medium  ?   quiet   f   closed  Internet
135107  22.1362534  -100.9335852    Potzocalli  Carretera Central Sn    San Luis Potosi ?   ?   ?   ?   No_Alcohol_Served   none    informal    completely  low ?   familiar    f   closed  none
135106  22.1497088  -100.9760928    El Rincón de San Francisco  Universidad 169 San Luis Potosi San Luis Potosi Mexico  ?   78000   Wine-Beer   only at bar informal    partially   medium  ?   familiar    f   open    none
```

## Sample Output :

```
placeID payment Cuisine parking_lot hours   days    latitude    longitude   name    address city    state   country fax zip alcohol smoking_area    dress_code  accessibility   price   url ambience    franchise   area    other_services
135110  cash    Spanish public  08:00-19:00;    Mon;Tue;Wed;Thu;Fri;                                                                            
135110  VISA    Spanish public  00:00-00:00;    Sat;                                                                            
135110  MasterCard-Eurocard Spanish public  00:00-00:00;    Sun;                                                                            
135110  American_Express    Spanish public  08:00-19:00;    Mon;Tue;Wed;Thu;Fri;                                                                            
135110  bank_debit_cards    Spanish public  00:00-00:00;    Sat;                                                                            
135110  bank_debit_cards    Spanish public  00:00-00:00;    Sun;                                                                            
135109  cash    Italian none    08:00-21:00;    Mon;Tue;Wed;Thu;Fri;    18.9217848  -99.2353499 Paniroles   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   Wine-Beer   not permitted   informal    no_accessibility    medium  ?   quiet   f   closed  Internet
135109  cash    Italian none    08:00-21:00;    Sat;    18.9217848  -99.2353499 Paniroles   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   Wine-Beer   not permitted   informal    no_accessibility    medium  ?   quiet   f   closed  Internet
135109  cash    Italian none    08:00-21:00;    Sun;    18.9217848  -99.2353499 Paniroles   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   Wine-Beer   not permitted   informal    no_accessibility    medium  ?   quiet   f   closed  Internet
135107  cash    Latin_American  none    07:00-23:30;    Mon;Tue;Wed;Thu;Fri;    22.1362534  -100.9335852    Potzocalli  Carretera Central Sn    San Luis Potosi ?   ?   ?   ?   No_Alcohol_Served   none    informal    completely  low ?   familiar    f   closed  none
135107  VISA    Latin_American  none    07:00-23:30;    Sat;    22.1362534  -100.9335852    Potzocalli  Carretera Central Sn    San Luis Potosi ?   ?   ?   ?   No_Alcohol_Served   none    informal    completely  low ?   familiar    f   closed  none
135107  MasterCard-Eurocard Latin_American  none    07:00-23:30;    Sun;    22.1362534  -100.9335852    Potzocalli  Carretera Central Sn    San Luis Potosi ?   ?   ?   ?   No_Alcohol_Served   none    informal    completely  low ?   familiar    f   closed  none
135107  American_Express    Latin_American  none    07:00-23:30;    Mon;Tue;Wed;Thu;Fri;    22.1362534  -100.9335852    Potzocalli  Carretera Central Sn    San Luis Potosi ?   ?   ?   ?   No_Alcohol_Served   none    informal    completely  low ?   familiar    f   closed  none
135107  bank_debit_cards    Latin_American  none    07:00-23:30;    Sat;    22.1362534  -100.9335852    Potzocalli  Carretera Central Sn    San Luis Potosi ?   ?   ?   ?   No_Alcohol_Served   none    informal    completely  low ?   familiar    f   closed  none
135107  MasterCard-Eurocard Latin_American  none    07:00-23:30;    Sun;    22.1362534  -100.9335852    Potzocalli  Carretera Central Sn    San Luis Potosi ?   ?   ?   ?   No_Alcohol_Served   none    informal    completely  low ?   familiar    f   closed  none
135106  cash    Mexican none    18:00-23:30;    Mon;Tue;Wed;Thu;Fri;    22.1497088  -100.9760928    El Rincón de San Francisco  Universidad 169 San Luis Potosi San Luis Potosi Mexico  ?   78000   Wine-Beer   only at bar informal    partially   medium  ?   familiar    f   open    none
135106  VISA    Mexican none    18:00-23:30;    Sat;    22.1497088  -100.9760928    El Rincón de San Francisco  Universidad 169 San Luis Potosi San Luis Potosi Mexico  ?   78000   Wine-Beer   only at bar informal    partially   medium  ?   familiar    f   open    none
135106  MasterCard-Eurocard Mexican none    18:00-21:00;    Sun;    22.1497088  -100.9760928    El Rincón de San Francisco  Universidad 169 San Luis Potosi San Luis Potosi Mexico  ?   78000   Wine-Beer   only at bar informal    partially   medium  ?   familiar    f   open    none
```

[image: excel screenshot]

I know this is a tedious task but help would be appreciated. I'm trying to use pandas. Not csvreader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
import pandas as pd

df_out = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')

for f in ('file2.csv','file3.csv','file4.csv','file4.csv','file5.csv'):
    df_out = df_out.merge(pd.read_csv(f),how='inner',on='placeID')

df_out.to_csv('output.csv')
```

Comment: it partially works, there is some data missing for, say, placeID 135110 in file 5, so after merging i want it to remain blank but still merged. Your code works however it ignores those rows where data is missing. So final output doesn't have placeID 135110 and its relevant data......

Comment: change `how='inner'` to `how='left'` and it will works as you said